# Is there a way to have a ggplot graph without an unused margin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've built a simple line plot in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

mortProb <- c(0,    0.01327,    0.00885,    0.03524,    0.01402,    0.07983,    0.09483,    0.16742,    0.40265)

vs <- c(0.0,    20.7855,    25.138625,  30.8095,    36.221375,  41.250375,  48.75,  58.527875,  100)

VS <- data.frame(vs, mortProb)

ggplot(VS) + geom_line(aes(vs, mortProb))
```

The graph I get is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rjRX.png)
[image]

What I want to get is just the plot inside of the black lines here (lines wouldn't actually show up in the graph.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfFaz.png)
[image]

Any ideas?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfFaz.png):

Comment: In addition to what are suggested in the answers, adding `theme_bw()` or `theme_classic()` will make the plot better

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(VS) + 
  geom_line(aes(vs, mortProb))+
  coord_cartesian(expand = expansion(mult = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to choose which axis to do this to and/or edit the scale of the axis at the same time, `scale_x_continuous()` and `scale_y_continuous` work.

```
library(ggplot2)
mortProb <- c(0,    0.01327,    0.00885,    0.03524,    0.01402,    0.07983,    0.09483,    0.16742,    0.40265)
vs <- c(0.0,    20.7855,    25.138625,  30.8095,    36.221375,  41.250375,  48.75,  58.527875,  100)
VS <- data.frame(vs, mortProb)
ggplot(VS) + 
  geom_line(aes(vs, mortProb)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```